# How to close cmd after run

Tags: batch-file

I have start.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set Catalog="\\10.1.1.1\Prog\"
set Nr=1
set UserName=""
set Password=""

pushd %Catalog%
start /B /HIGH /MIN /WAIT "" prog.EXE .F. .F. %Nr% %UserName% %Password%

popd

cmd /c exit
exit
exit 0
exit /B
start /B "" cmd /c exit
move nul 2>&0
```

Problems:

1. cmd window always on top
2. cmd window not closing after start prog.exe
3. cmd closing only if closed prog.exe

so how to close current start.bat after run prog.exe without closing  prog.exe?

Comment: What is the specific reason for using `START`? and please explain the exact purpose of your use of each of the following `START` options, `/B`, `/HIGH`, `/MIN`, and `/WAIT`?

Comment: @Compo i need run program from network disk, and close cmd after program runned, also want not to show cmd windows black screen at all

Comment: You cannot generally run a batch file without its cmd.exe window showing, without doing so via some other language/utility. At best, you'll see a flash of one, for each individual cmd.exe window invoked using the `/Min` option with `Start`. You were asked to explain your use of all of those options, but have not done so. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to read its help and usage information. Please also update your question to provide to us the exact program and version, you are trying to run like this, _(revealing it is not a privacy issue)_.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `start /B /WAIT`, where the application starts in the console, the `start` cmd then waits for the child to terminate before following through the rest of the batch.  By removing `/WAIT`, the command will follow through without waiting for the child process.

Then properly terminate your batch with simply `exit` to close the terminal.

Comment: without /wait program not starting as pushd %Catalog% very slow switching

Comment: You could try a [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).  If you use: 

`pushd %Catalog% && start /B /HIGH /MIN ...`

Start won't run until pushed has successfully completed.

Comment: Another option to try would be to add a `timeout 1 >nul`. If one second is still too long, you could try `0`, but that doesn't always work

Comment: @senior-pomidor Did adding a logical AND condition (`&&`) fix the issue of the pushed directories not being set in time?  All together, with the correct `exit`, is the console closing properly after?  `start /wait` will halt processes in the script until completed/closed, which is why you never reach the end when the `start` process/child is running.